# React request is being sent without an Authorization header

Tags: reactjs, http-headers, authorization, bearer-token, fastify

I am trying to pass a bearer token, to the fastify http server, in my headers.

I set the headers inside my request as:

```
...
const headers = {
  Accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
if (token) {
  headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
}
const newOptions = {
  ...options,
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers
}
console.log('options:', newOptions)
return fetch(url, newOptions)
```

My console.log prints:

```
options: {
  mode: "no-cors", 
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    Content-Type: "application/json",
    Authorization: "Bearer NQ9xQLmYtq92aT8JHHRd7DGZJ..."
  }
}
```

From the Chrome network tab, I look at the headers, and `Authorization` is just not present there. My route handler function is below:

```
async function user(server, options) {
  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/user/:email',
    handler: async (req, res) => {
      const username = req.params.email
      console.log('user email:', username)
      console.log('headers:', req.headers)
      res.send({
        type: 'promoter'
      })
    }
  })
}
```

When I print headers on the server, it also does not have `Authorization`, showing:

```
headers: { host: 'localhost:5000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  accept: 'application/json',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.106 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'no-cors',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/admin',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8' }
```

What am I missing?

Another interesting issue is that when I run the request from `Postman` it shows 200 response code, and fastify prints `200` to the log. However, running from the saga/request with:

```
  return fetch(url, newOptions)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
```

I get `response.status` of `0` instead of `200` inside the request method, while the server log still shows `"res":{"statusCode":200}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem.

Apparently, my version of Chrome - `Version 80.0.3987.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and possibly other browsers and older versions of Chrome, as well, strip the `authorization` header, when it is used in conjunction with the `no-cors` mode. Enabling `CORS` and setting the appropriate headers solves the problem.

Comment: This solution would be more useful if you displayed the headers you added :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `withCredentials: true` and `credentials: 'include'` to your options:

```js
options: {
  mode: "no-cors",
  withCredentials: true, // <-- ADD THIS
  credentials: 'include', // <-- AND THIS
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    Content-Type: "application/json",
    Authorization: "Bearer NQ9xQLmYtq92aT8JHHRd7DGZJ..."
  }
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Comment: unfortunately, makes no difference. i am wondering whether it is possible that fastify disables authorization header somehow, disallowing it during the negotiation.

Comment: I have seen that with some servers where the authorization headers are blocked by a server configuration setting. I am not familiar with fastify, although you should still see in your network tab of dev tools that the header is passing.

Comment: Is it sending an OPTIONS preflight request? Perhaps this is a CORS issue.

Comment: I have the `no-cors` mode enabled and it sends the request to another port. I think that `CORS` is an unlikely candidate, but maybe. Thank you to helping to solve this. Much appreciated.